# Reacts JS-mdb react table pagination

Tags: reactjs

I am getting below error while doing mdb react table pagination,Please help

1.arrow' is not exported from 'react-popper'
2.Target[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBMsT.jpg) is not exported from 'react-popper'

Comment: Please add your code, else no one is able to answer your question.

Comment: the problem is same code is working in my pc when i imported using npm install mdbreact and after i copied related modules to my office PC.In my office dev server is giving arrow is not exported from react-popper

Comment: Well, there can be many reasons why your code is not running on another system. So we need code or more details. Right now, no one can answer your question.

Comment: I tried code in below link.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the comment under your question you wrote that you used the example from the link but this link refers to the MDB jQuery documentation and if I understood correctly the question concerns MDB React. Try to use this link ---->  https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/pagination/.

I think this may be the reason for your error.

But you only paste here a wrong link and you use a correct example in your project, please reinstall your dependency:
remove `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` / `package-lock.json` or both.

Then run the command `npm i` or `yarn` in the terminal and try again. In most similar cases this solution works.

Best!